# Override Bootstrap 3 Class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 control-label class has padding-top: 7px. I want to override it with value of 0 px.

I have my CSS (my.min.css) where I specified the class as follows:

```
.control-label {
    padding-top: 0px:
}
```

I placed my css (my.min.css) after Bootstrap.css

But it does not work and when I look at the Developers Tool in the browser (IE 10) I see that class .control-label in my.min.css appears before the Bootstrap.css and the value of padding-top: 0px is crossed over.  And right below my.min.css is the following line:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label, .form-horizontal .radio, and so on
   padding-top: 7px;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The Bootstrap version has higher specificity.  Either define your selector with the same specificity (`.form-horizontal .control-label`) or override (i.e. use `!important`).